# Include Custom Object (from external API) in SalesForce Global Search

Tags: visualforce

We've got a local application that provides and stores user credentials.  We use SalesForce as our CRM and support tool.  We have created an API that will essentially provide a SOAP interface to get a list of users from our local application.  I'm pretty confident we can build that table display and user list page.

However, what would be icing on the cake would be to make the list of users searchable from the SF global search.  It is my understanding that you have to have custom objects (tables) created so that SF can search them.  In our scenario we wouldn't actually have a true custom object as we load the data from an external API on the page.

Is it possible to include external API call result sets in the SF global search tool?

Comment: @mast0r Oh cool.  Had not clue that even existed, albeit in beta.